# How to fix casting androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton cannot be cast to com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-appcompat, androidx, android-textinputedittext

My code was working fine but today after the running gave me the next error:

androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton cannot be cast to com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

The error at line 92 :    `verify_code = findViewById(R.id.verify_code);`

The application breaks when the activity started , and i got the following error

The java code

```
public class PhoneLoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText InputUserPhoneNumber, InputUserVerificationCode;
    private Button SendVerificationCodeButton, VerifyButton;
    private long backPressedTime;
    private Toast backToast;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks callbacks;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private TextInputLayout phone_num;
    private TextInputLayout verify_code;
    private ProgressDialog loadingBar;
    private DatabaseReference dbRef;
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    private String mVerificationId;
    String lat;
    private StorageReference mStorageRef;
    String uid;
    String lng;
    String phone_number;
    private PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken mResendToken;
    public static final int Request_Code_Granded_Premission = 1408;
    private static final String TAG = "PhoneLoginActivity";
    private String ph_num;
    boolean check = false;
    private String phone_jor;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        dbRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("Guest");
        InputUserPhoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone_text);
        InputUserVerificationCode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pwd_text);
        SendVerificationCodeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
        VerifyButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.verify_button);
        loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);
        phone_num = findViewById(R.id.phone_number);
        verify_code = findViewById(R.id.verify_code);

        phone_number = InputUserPhoneNumber.getText().toString();

    .
    .
    .


            }

}
```

The xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:id="@+id/log_in"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="30dp"
    tools:context=".Activities.PhoneLoginActivity"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/circle"
        android:layout_width="146dp"
        android:layout_height="121dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"

        app:srcCompat="@drawable/circle_logo" />


    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/hello"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/circle"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/hello_word"
        android:textSize="14dp" />




    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@+id/hello"

        android:id="@+id/hello2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/hello2"
        android:textSize="14dp" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/hello2"
        android:gravity="top|center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"

        >

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/phone_number"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:theme="@style/TextLabel">


            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/phone_text"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/ed_phone"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:textColor="#064065"
                android:textColorHint="#064065"
                 />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/verify_code"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-75dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:theme="@style/TextLabel"
            android:visibility="invisible">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/pwd_text"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/ed_pwd"
                android:inputType="number"

                android:textColor="#064065"
                android:textColorHint="#064065"
              />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


        <Button

            android:id="@+id/login_btn"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_login"
            android:text="@string/login"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"

            />

        <Button

            android:id="@+id/verify_button"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-50dp"
            android:text="@string/verify"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"

            android:visibility="invisible" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And The erorr

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.awshakam1998.bottleofwater, PID: 31185
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.awshakam1998.bottleofwater/com.awshakam1998.bottleofwater.Activities.PhoneLoginActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton cannot be cast to com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3302)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1891)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton cannot be cast to com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        at com.awshakam1998.bottleofwater.Activities.PhoneLoginActivity.onCreate(PhoneLoginActivity.java:92)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7372)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1218)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3147)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3302) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1891) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
```

Comment: Could you please check line number 92 in PhoneLoginActivity and add it in question too?

Comment: check the question again

Answer (score -1):

I think , there is no error in code . Could you please uninstall the app from device .rebuild and install the app again.

Comment: I tried and also closed the software and then opened it again and the following error appeared during the running :

org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks

Comment: Could you please provide stack trace for the same?